# Continuos Signal to MATLAB Function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

How can I introduce a continuos signal to a MATLAB Function block so I can get a continuos output.

My MATLAB Function block will be this:

```
function y = fcn(u)
y = 2*exp(-u);
```

So I can get a negative exponential, this because I need a control voltage source with a negative exponential signal. I need to introduce a controlled voltage source a exponential signal, is there other way?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in Matlab is continuous-time. Everything is discrete-time, despite what Simulink may say. The only way to represent a continuous-time waveform is to discretize time and sample that waveform (respecting Nyquist criterion), turning it into a discrete-time signal

Comment: @LuisMendo Simulink distinguishes between "continuous" signals and "discrete" signals, which have a discrete sample time (continuous signals do not). I think it's in that context that the OP meant a continuous signal.

Comment: @am304 My point was that the signals that Simulink considers to be "continuous" are internally represented as discrete-time samples. It simply hides the sampling to the user. Or does it really represent continuous signals without sampling (for instance, parametrically)?

Comment: @LuisMendo see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/types-of-sample-time.html for the definition of a "continuous" sample time. You are right in that it is of course discrete, but the number of time steps (minor/major) taken varies dynamically as the simulation progresses based on the solver and associated settings (tolerance, etc...). A discrete sample time on the other hand, takes a fixed number of time steps at regular intervals.

Comment: @am304 Thanks. I see more cleearly now how Simulink handles "continuous" signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a MATLAB function to do that: take your input signal, multiply it by -1 with a [Gain](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/gain.html) block, then use a [Math Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/mathfunction.html) block set to `exp`, and finally another [Gain](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/gain.html) block to multiply it by 2.

Second, your input signal can be whatever you want. For example, you can use a [Sine Wave](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/sinewave.html) block, or choose whatever block you want from the `Sources` library. If you leave the `Sample Time` parameter to 0, you will have a "continuous" signal (in the Simulink sense of the word), see [Specify Sample Time](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/how-to-specify-the-sample-time.html) in the documentation for more details. You can also use your own data from the MATLAB workspace using a [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block.

Comment: Nice! The Constant Signal works! but when I want to generate the exponential signal it show constant, this is the image http://i.imgur.com/drzVJJx.png
why is that ?

Comment: What is the frequency of the sine wave block? What solver/sample time are you using for the model?

Comment: Nevermind, I use the Ramp Function with scope 1 to generate the "X" values (2..3..4..5..) and the rest of the blocks exactly as you said! Thanks a lot!